How are tkinter's fill, side, expand options in pack interacting with each other?
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(master=None, width=200, height=100, bg="red")
frame1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.TOP, expand=False)

frame2 = tk.Frame(master=None, width=100, height=50, bg="yellow")
frame2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.TOP, expand=False)

frame3 = tk.Frame(master=None, width=50, height=25, bg="blue")
frame3.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.TOP, expand=False)

window.mainloop()

fill and side interactions
Problem is I expect tk.BOTH to fill vertically when I drag window down, but it does not (seen by grey background of window). It only fills horizontally.

When i change all 3 frames' sides from tk.TOP to tk.LEFT, it fills vertically but not horizontally

Based on above 2 experiments, is it true side value changes behavior of fill=tk.BOTH, making it work only in 1 direction each time?
To further test, with side=tk.LEFT, I changed tk.BOTH in all frames to tk.Y, then tk.X.
tk.Y behaves the same as tk.BOTH. tk.X still does not fill horizontally, but now also does not fill vertically (as expected)
fill and expand interactions
If I set all 3 frames expand = True, all the previously failed fills are now successfully filling in both directions no matter side is tk.TOP or tk.LEFT.
I'm confused did the fill=tk.BOTH now work because of expand=True, or tk.BOTH still does not work, and expand took over the role of filling for the failed direction?
If the latter, what's the purpose of tk.BOTH since it always fails to fill in 1 direction depending on side, and depends on expand=True to make up for it's failures?

There's a very good explanation of the pack geometry manager here.
You can think of the fill option as "fill the container you're in" and the expand option as "change size to take up as much space as possible in the parent widget"
The linked article summarizes expand and fill as follows (likely better than I):
Expand

The expand determines whether the widget should expand to occupy any extra spaces allocated to the container.
If the expand is set to True, the widget will expand, and if set to False, it will not. The expand parameter defaults to False.
The expand parameter is highly dependent on the side parameter.

Fill

The fill determines if a widget will occupy the available space. It accepts the following values: ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘both’, and ‘none’. By default, the fill is ‘none’.

